# Make the high/low values in step wise from a range in google sheet

Tags: typescript, google-apps-script, numbers, step

Need google app script to make stepwise to an array of numbers taken from  a range cell values. Example suppose the taken cell  values  from A column are as:
A1  1
A2  4
A3  2
A4  1
A5  4
The result cell values in B column should as follows:
B1  1
B2  1
B3  2
B4  2
B5  3
B6  3
(B7  4)
(B8  4)
B9  3
B10  3
(B11  2)
(B12  2)
(B13  1)
(B14  1)
B15  2
B16  2
B17  3
B18  3
(B19  4)
(B20  4)
The logic is make the every recent  high/low numbers by adding/subtracting by 1 from previous number till reach the recent numbers by double entry of the same to make stepwise. In result B column The numbers in bracket are the cell values of A column and not in bracket are new numbers to be add as per logic.

Comment: or may be by formula. Pls share a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Description**

I believe what you want is that between 2 values, increment between them either +1 or -1 depending on the difference between the 2 values.

**Script**

```
function test() {
  try {
    let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Test");
    let values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    let result = [values[0][0],values[0][0]];
    for( let i=0; i<values.length-1; i++ ) {
      let diff = values[i+1][0]-values[i][0];
      let inc = diff < 0 ? -1 : 1;
      diff = Math.abs(diff);
      let current = values[i][0];
      for( let j=0; j<diff; j++ ) {
        current = current+inc;
        result.push(current,current);
      }
    }
    result = result.map( item => [item] );  // turn result into 2D array
    sheet.getRange(1,2,result.length,1).setValues(result);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

**Screen shot**

[image]